# Toolbar don´t work with pre-lollipops devices using appcompat v7

Tags: android, toolbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm doing a simple code for a toolbar and menu drawer, using material appcompatv7.
Everything **works perfectly on the Nexus 5 with lollipop**, but in a pre-lollipop (4.1 or 4.4) device crashes.
The problem comes in defining the style.
I put my code if anyone can tell me where the fault is.

This is my main activity:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Hello extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, 
                drawerLayout, 
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);

        ListView lv_navigation_drawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_navigation_drawer);
        lv_navigation_drawer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                new String[] {"Screen 1", "Screen 2", "Screen 3"}));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

The main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Style by simply extending Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (I have no style defined for values-v21)

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>
</resources>
```

**This all works correctly on devices lollipop and pre-lollipop.** The problem comes when want to customize the colors of the toolbar and status bar

I make this change in **values/styles**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2ecc71</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#27ae60</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <color name="primary">#457C50</color>
    <color name="primaryDarker">#580C0C</color>
</resources>
```

and I add style to the **values-v21**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

As said earlier, this works fine on the Nexus 5 but although the UI comes with correct colors, I can not see the ListView is inside the Menu Drawer (I do not understand why) ..**.but in the "pre-lollipop" devices crashes.**
The error throws me is this:

> ...java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an
>   action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your
>   theme to use a Toolbar instead.

I searched a lot of information about this error and tried many options: the item windowActionBar within the style is "false" in the main activity have become "Toolbar" to "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar" but without success ...
I have also searched for examples already given, but not working for me
I'm using Eclipse, the target of manifiest 21 and the minimum is 16, I have also updated sdk and adt ...

Can anyone help to work correctly on devices pre-lollipop?

Comment: The the answer work for you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead.

To call  `setSupportActionBar` you can't have another action bar. That's why you get

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor

Make sure your theme doesn't have an actionbar to use toolbar.

Comment: Working! Thanks Folks ;)