# ActionBar Not Supported

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I am having problem displaying the action bar in my application in android < 5.0.

[image]

^^In 4.4, its not displaying. Action bar is not visible

But same application when opened in android 5.0 its displaying perfectly.

[image]

```
My activity_main
http://pastebin.com/F2c6BGj9
Manifest
http://pastebin.com/AJ7pnbMB
drawer_row
http://pastebin.com/L6de0TnM
styles.xml
http://pastebin.com/0tVpDV3M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is because your style is :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Try with:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

**UPDATE:**

Your logcat says:

```
This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

You must be calling `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` in your activity and you haven't post your java code and after looking at the code in your `main_activity.xml`  I belive that you're using the toolbar, not the action bar, so maybe the answer I gave to you wouldn't work, and looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971929/toolbar-don%C2%B4t-work-with-pre-lollipops-devices-using-appcompat-v7), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087551/crashed-when-applied-toolbar) I think that you should put this instead of what I said before:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Comment: I get the following error "Unfortunately Application_Name has stopped"
Logcat:
http://pastebin.com/87J2nzCd